# .htaccess redirect with all parameters

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple rule in the `.htaccess` file, to redirect all requests to `inwork.php`:

```
RewriteRule .* php/inwork.php?refpage=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

But all parameters are missing. For the request `http://example.com/example.php?check=1&check=2`, I get `example.php` in `inwork.php` for `$_GET['refpage']`. But I want `example.php?check=1&check=2` in `inwork.php`. (There are requests with many parameters in different orders, so I don't want to write them manually in `.htaccess`.)

Edit: Full htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml         text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.de [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.de/$1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html /$1 [NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/pics/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* php/inwork.php?refpage=%{REQUEST_URI} [B,L]
```

Comment: Do you have a preceding condition to this `RewriteRule` that prevents an undesirable "loop"?

Comment: I don't have a specific loop-preventing rule, but that isn't a problem. The inwork.php file handles all request (also "bad" requests)

Comment: Right, it's just that by itself, the above directive would not work as intended on a default Apache install... the rewriting process starts over (a second time) and ends up rewriting to `php/inwork.php?refpage=/php/inwork.php` - In other words, it rewrites to itself and `refpage` ends up containing the script that is processing the request, instead of the URL being requested. If that isn't happening then there must be some other interaction we are not seeing... other directives, other `.htaccess` files (perhaps in the `/php` subdirectory)?

Comment: You can "edit" your question to add the relevant code. Apart from "looking like a confusing mess", posting unformatted code (especially regex, URLs and XML-like tags) can result in characters being omitted from display.

Comment: Thanks - I edited it on the original question and deleted "the mess".

Comment: Just to clarify, when you request `/example.php?check=1&check=2` then presumably `/example.php` doesn't actually exist in the root?

Comment: The site normally based only on ".html"-requests. If a "example.html"-request comes in, the inwork.php generates a new "example.html" on the server. The "example.php?check=1&check=2" was an exception. But I tried it with an existing example.php-file and without (in this case the inwork.php puts out an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** Alternatively, just rewrite to `php/inwork.php` and parse the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead, which already contains the URL-path and query string from the initial request. (Note that the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP variable is different to the `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable, despite the name being the same.)

---

The `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable contains the URL-path only, not the query string. If you want to include the query string from the original URL and *make this part of the `refpage` URL parameter* then you need to append the query string as an additional step.

However, I think it is "easier" to grab the entire URL (URL-path + query string) from the `THE_REQUEST` Apache server variable and pass this instead:

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/.+)\s
RewriteRule ^ php/inwork.php?refpage=%1 [B,L]
```

The `%1` backreference contains the full URL (URL-path + query string) from `THE_REQUEST`, which contains the initial line from the HTTP request (eg. `GET /example.php?check=1&check=2 HTTP/1.1`).

The `B` `RewriteRule` flag URL encodes the captured backreference - necessary in order to make sure everything ultimately belongs to the `refpage` URL parameter and not become part of the query string on the rewritten request.

You'll then need to manually parse the complete URL (value of the `refpage` URL param) into its component parts with PHP (which I assume you are already doing)...

For example... given a request for `/example.php?check=1&check=2` then the PHP variable `$_GET['refpage']` now contains `/example.php?check=1&check=2` (having been automatically URL decoded by PHP). (Possibly just your hasty example, but the two `check` URL params will need special treatment if you want to avoid the later overwriting the former.)

---

However, unless you have a specific requirement to do it this way, I would simply parse the PHP superglobal `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead (as mentioned at the top of my answer). This already contains the complete URL from the request - the same value you are manually assigning to the `refpage` URL parameter. You can then simplify your rewrite:

```
RewriteRule .* php/inwork.php [L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index.html [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html /$1 [NC,R=301]
> ```

You are missing the `L` flag on the `RewriteRule` directive. This is a potential problem, since if this directive is triggered (removing `index.html`) processing will continue and will likely be *externally redirected* to `/php/inwork.php`. However, this shouldn't have affected your example URLs.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/pics/(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule .* php/inwork.php?refpage=%{REQUEST_URI} [B,L]
> ```

The first condition here (checking that the request does not map to file) is what prevents the undesirable second loop back to itself.

The second condition that checks that `/pics/` is not present in the URL-path can be simplified from `!^(.*)/pics/(.*)$` to `!/pics/`. (No need for capturing subpatterns if they are not being used.)

The `B` flag is not required here. However, by using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable, you will naturally lose the query string parameters.

What you can try, is using the `QSA` flag on the `RewriteRule`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/pics/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* php/inwork.php?refpage=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

Although this won't do specifically what you are asking, as the query string parameters won't be part of the `refpage` URL param, they will be merged with the URL you are rewriting to and consequently should be available in PHP's `$_GET` array. For example, given a request for `/example.php?check=1&check=2` then the `$_GET` array would be populated as follows:

```
Array (
  'refpage' => '/example.php',
  'check' => '2',
)
```

(Because the `check` URL param is duplicated.)

Additionally, you should also make sure that MultiViews is disabled. Although whether this is actually causing problems in this instance is dependent on your file structure. (It shouldn't be an issue with the example URL you posted.)

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
```

Comment: Unfourtanetely - RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/.+)\s
RewriteRule ^ php/inwork.php?refpage=%1 [B,L] - get me an 403 Error: "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server" and $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in php doesn't contain the paramters. (if I have the complete url in the inwork.php file, it is no problem: I'm good in php, but really bad in the .htaccess stuff)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem in another way without paramters - thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. However, the above shouldn't have resulted in a 403 (given the example URL as stated) and nor should the PHP variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` be absent of parameters in the second example. Perhaps there was a conflict with existing directives? There would certainly seem to be "something else" going on here, given the behaviour of your directive in the question. (?)

Comment: I have posted my whole htaccess above (as comment). Perhaps there are strange server-adjustments. I don't know, it isn't my own server.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok thats very interesting - I will try it next week..